# Apache 2.4 [proxy_http:error] [proxy:error]

Tags: apache-2.4, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy

I have enabled Apache proxy and http_proxy modules in order to reverse proxy some requests coming on port 80, only for a virtualhost, to localhost:3000 (where nuxt with node is running).

The proxy configuration in the virtualhost is pretty easy:

```
ProxyRequests off
<Proxy *>
 Require all granted
</Proxy>
ProxyPreserveHost on
ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/ retry=1 acquire=3000 timeout=3000 keepalive=off
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/
 ProxyTimeout 3000
 ProxyVia full
```

Apache version is: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)

**The problem** is in the apache error log which is literally flooded by these two errors repeated intermittently:

```
[proxy_http:error] [pid :pid] (20014)Internal error (specific information not available): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx] AH01102: error reading status line from remote server localhost:3000
[proxy:error] [pid :pid] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx] AH00898: Error reading from remote server returned by /
```

I have followed many guides and suggestions (SetEnv proxy-initial-not-pooled 1, keepalive off, bla bla) but none helped. Anyone have a clue about this thing? Maybe it's not even an error and it must be so because ProxyRequests are off? However I can't have the log flooded by only this two errors.

Answer (score 1):

`[proxy:error] [pid :pid] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx] AH00898: Error reading from remote server returned by /`
This means that Apache could not read the response from the service behind `ProxyPass`. Perhaps the service on port 3000 actually does have issues serving it's content. Try looking for the issue there, try accessing the port directly.

Comment: The service behind ProxyPass is node on localhost 3000, I think the problem is they are trying to use our server as proxy because I discoverd the last admin left ProxyRequests On. Now I have fixed this issue but we are probably listed as open proxy somewhere in internet. The major problem now is the Apache log that is flooded. I've also try with ufw blocking IP or Sub but still it's a nightmare. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding starting & ending quote(`""`) around slash(`/`) ?

Means:

```
ProxyPass "/" "http://localhost:3000/" retry=1 acquire=3000 timeout=3000 keepalive=off
ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://localhost:3000/"
```

May be it's causing trouble.

Reference: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html